# Probability of winning 4 games in a series of games

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value

I saw some similar questions but I am still not sure of my solution

we have a series of 7 games and 2 teams the first to win 4 games wins the title and we have a given win probability for both of the teams P=$\frac1{2}$.

1. given $X$ a random variable which is equal to the number of games that the teams will play $X$ gets the values of $4,5,6,7$
2. given $Y$ represents a random variable of the games team 'A' played and won.

For the first part I used the negative binomial distribution $P(X = i) = \binom{i-1}{r-1}p^{r} (1-p)^{i-r}$

so what I got was $P(X = 4) = \binom{4-1}{4-1}(\frac1{2})^{4} (1-p)^{4-4}$$=\frac1{16}$ for 4 games

for 5 games I got  $P(X = 5) = \binom{5-1}{4-1}(\frac1{2})^{4} (1-p)^{5-4}$$=\frac1{8}$

for 6 games $P(X = 6) = \binom{6-1}{4-1}(\frac1{2})^{4} (1-p)^{6-4}$$=\frac5{32}$

and for 7 games $P(X = 7) = \binom{7-1}{4-1}(\frac1{2})^{4} (1-p)^{7-4}$$=\frac5{32}$

then I multiplied each of the results by ${2\choose 1}$ because we need to choose one of the 2 teams.

for the second part of the question I could not think of a way to start it as I could not really understand what they meant it says - given $Y$ represents a random variable of the games team 'A' played and won.

appreciate any tips and help thank you!

P.S

for the first part of the question am I supposed to use $E[X]=\frac r{p}$ or $E[X]=n*p$ for the expectation?

Comment: @parsiad my bad , edited

Comment: To analyze $Y$, distinguish two cases:  Either $A$ wins the series (in which case $A$ won exactly $4$ games) or $B$ wins, and you have already computed the relevant probabilities in that case.

Comment: @lulu can you please explain a bit more ? I am still struggling with this thank you!

Comment: What don't you get?  Half the time $A$ wins the series, in which case $A$ wins exactly $4$ games.  The other half of the time $B$ wins and you already worked out that case (If $B$ wins in four games then $A$ wins $0$, if $B$ wins in five games then $A$ wins $1$, and so on).